# usage of require within angularjs: any alternative

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, libphonenumber

I am tryinng to use `google-libphonenumber` which is at the following [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber) in my angularjs 1.5 application.

The usage of this library as mentioned in the link:

```
// Require `PhoneNumberFormat`.
var PNF = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberFormat;
 
// Get an instance of `PhoneNumberUtil`.
var phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
 
// Parse number with country code.
var phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse('202-456-1414', 'US');
 
// Print number in the international format.
console.log(phoneUtil.format(phoneNumber, PNF.INTERNATIONAL));
```

since `require` is a server side function that is expected to be used with nodejs, its not working with angularjs.

How can i use this in angularjs controller in order to utilize the functions it provide?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use require in the browser, you would need to use `browserify` for example. Another way is to include the file `dist/libphonenumber.js` with a script tag in your page ans use it this way :

```
var PNF = libphonenumber.PhoneNumberFormat;
...
```

No magic, I read the source code and if it detects it is in a browser context, it binds libphonenumber to window.

Comment: In addition to this, bower has some results for people who have implemented a bower version.  One example is https://ruimarinho.github.io/google-libphonenumber/